# How to solve the integral $\int\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}\,dx$ .

Tags: integration

> $$\large \int \frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}~dx$$

In this I tried to substitute $x^2 +1$ by $t$.

after that got stuck.

Comment: It would be better if you type your question, this shows your seriousness towards this question and this forum .

Comment: As written, I am afraid that you would face elliptic integrals.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Surprisingly, it can be done with elementary functions. See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1044850/1242

Comment: @HansLundmark. Thank you ! I am always afraid by things such as $\sqrt{x^4+1}$ in denominator and my first (and stupid) instinct is to think about elliptic integrals. Cheers :-(

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What if I tell you that by doing elementary integrals, you will get $\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \arccos{\frac{\sqrt2x}{1+x^2}}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I would say that's a very good instinct in general!

Comment: @JaideepKhare : In a previous comment, I confessed my stupidity. I shall just repeat. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$x^2-1=x^2\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)$$

As $\displaystyle\int\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)dx=x+\dfrac1x$

write
$$x^2+1=x\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)$$

$$x^4+1=x^2\left(x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}\right)\implies\sqrt{x^4+1}=|x|\sqrt{x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}}$$

Finally $ x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}=\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)^2-2$