# Can we compute $\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx$ is terms of elementary functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

everyone!

I am trying to compute this integral
$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx$$
for $|x|<1$.

I used some computational softwares and the solution is always in terms of "non-elementary functions". I tried to use some substitutions and also integration by parts to compute it, however with no success.

Anyone has any idea to compute this?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Usually when you have a square root of a cubic or quartic polynomial, it's an elliptic integral. It's only in exceptional cases that you can evaluate it in terms of elementary functions (like in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041531/how-to-evaluate-these-indefinite-integrals-with-sqrt1x4), for example).

Comment: When you say " for $|x|<1$", do you mean you're interested in an antiderivative with domain $|x|<1$ or do you mean you want to evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1}$? If it's the former then as your software suggests, the integral is non-elementary, so the best you'll get is an antiderivative in terms of special functions. If it's the latter, you can obtain a closed form using the Beta function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the method of [integration of differential binomial](https://planetmath.org/integrationofdifferentialbinomial):
$$
a=2,\quad, b=4,\quad c=\frac{-1}{2}
$$
the answer seems to be `No!`

Comment: Cool! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! :)